# Parsing the data packet received from serial port

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing, serial-port

I am getting the response from the serial port through below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SerialPortHexCommunication
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
        port.PortName = "COM5";
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        if (port.IsOpen)
        {
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }
         port.Open();

        byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[6] { 0xD0, 0xF2, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x06, 0xC7 };

        port.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        Console.ReadKey();
        port.Close();
        port.Dispose();

    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data receive at time "+ DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;

        int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];

        if (port.BytesToRead > 1)
        {
            port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }

        foreach (byte item in buffer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output is basically the dec representation of the bytes and the hardware connected to serial port send it in these format
E0 ,F2 ,device id ,2 bytes length,current date,current time(store both current date and current time in more than 2 bytes by right shifting and some other data)

I am receiving data in chunks sometimes 4 bytes, sometimes 8 bytes. What i want to do is
1.I want to check first what i have received in that data packet like header
2.Then when i received next data block i do not want to check for header but for next information like date and time and so on..

Basically i want to parse the incoming packet.

can anyone please give an small example.It will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: i can also upload the code of hardware response if anyone wants

Comment: Generally, how it works is you know when you have obtained the whole message.  A lot of protocols end their message with a `<CR><LF>`, you need something to let you know you have the whole message.  You should build your string in the `DataReceivedHandler` like you are, and when you see that you have the whole message, parse the string to get all the relevant data.

Comment: @Baddack Thanks for the resposne.Is there any way of using circular buffer or dynamic array to store the the data that is sent by serial port at a time and then parse what is avilable in the bufffer and then again put data into it and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I use `StringBuilder` to build my strings.  In your case, you are working with bytes, maybe you can use a global `byte[]` array.  Below is an example where `<LF>` means I got the whole message.  I append characters to my string until I know I have the whole message.  I clear the buffer quickly, because your next string can be coming in while you are evaluating.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char LF = (char)10;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            //do something with your response 'CurrentLine'
            Eval_String(CurrentLine);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you get the whole message you can evaluate it for what you need.  In my example, my message comes back comma delimited, so I can split my string into a string array using a comma as my delimiter and get each value from the message.

```
public void Eval_String(string s)
{
    string[] eachParam;
    eachParam = s.Split(',');

    if (eachParam.Length == 5)
    {
        //do something
        Console.WriteLine(eachParam[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.But can you do the same with the circular buffer having two pointers one to write and one to read.I know there is no default implementation of circular buffer provided in c# so i am using https://github.com/joaoportela/CircullarBuffer-CSharp.